# Making the "main" class div to fill the entire page with Razor

Tags: bootstrap-4, blazor

My first project with .NET Core Blazor platform is harder than I thought.

Out of the box, the project created the MainLayout.razor file.  I am trying to modify the "main" class, so
it will fill the whole page, but with no success.  Here what I have now:

```
<div class="main mh-100 p-0" style="background-color:#1100ff">
 <nav class="navbar">
  <label class="navbar-brand">My Project</label>
 </nav>
 <div class="container p-0 align-self-center" style="background-color:#ff99ff">
  <div class="content">
   @Body
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I thought mh-100 is supposed to force the max-height to 100%.  Any help is greatly appreciated and I apology in advance if there's already another similar question out there.

Comment: It's 100% of the container, your body should have 100% height too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is not a blazor issue and has nothing to do how blazor works, but if a correct css style is applied it will fix your issue. What you have to do is apply the height of your screen. Take a look at what css units are and what will work best for you: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

In your case, you need the height of viewport:

```
div {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/umair_me/pen/oNxovxX

In bootstrap you can use `min-vh-100` or `vh-100` for bootstrap 4.2+ versions. More details [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-viewport)

Comment: this apparently solved my problem.  Do you know if there's a Bootstrap equivalent class that I can use?

Comment: Yes I have updated the answer with bootstrap classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think this is really a Blazor type problem but a HTML/CSS problem. Besides of bootstrap, if you add a `width:100%;` to your style tag, this should solve the problem.

The problem could also be that you set the max-height to 100%, you should look at the (normal) height rather.